# NSPredicate format string doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, foundation

In my code, I want to check and see if a record already exists, so I know whether to create it or update it. But I ran into a problem. The problem is when I use this:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ == %@", ATTRIBUTE_ID, idNumber];
[request setPredicate:pred];
```

This doesn't work. It always claims no results were found. However, it works just fine when I rewrite it like so:

```
NSExpression *lhs = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:ATTRIBUTE_ID];
NSExpression *rhs = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:idNumber];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSComparisonPredicate
                                     predicateWithLeftExpression:lhs
                                     rightExpression:rhs
                                     modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier
                                     type:NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType
                                     options:0];
[request setPredicate:pred];
```

What am I missing or doing incorrectly in the format string?

Comment: Monolo's answer is right, but I would recommend using this approach instead of the format one. This one is faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `ATTRIBUTE_ID` is a key, so you should use `%K` in the format string for that part of it.

The format string would look like this (upper case K as pointed out in the comments):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", ATTRIBUTE_ID, idNumber];
```

Comment: Thanks Monolo! One correction--I think it has to be an uppercase %K to work