# Using NSPredicate to filter an NSArray of objects based on a property which is an NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I have an NSArray of objects with the following properties

```
@objc class Dummy: NSObject {
    let propertyOne: Int
    let propertyTwo: Int
    let propertyThree: NSDictionary
}
```

In `propertyThree`, it will have certain key values pairs such as

```
keyOne => valueOne
keyTwo => valueTwo
keyThree => valueThree
```

I want to filter through my NSArray of Dummy Objects based off of `keyOne` of the `NSDictionary` that is a property of the `Dummy` object.

How would I go about doing this? I looked through:

- [Using NSPredicate to filter an NSArray based on NSDictionary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958622/using-nspredicate-to-filter-an-nsarray-based-on-nsdictionary-keys?rq=1#)
- [Filtering NSArray of NSDictionary objects using NSPredicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505154/filtering-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects-using-nspredicate)

But it doesn't seem applicable.

Comment: How about using the `filter` method on your array? You just need to provide a closure which returns true or false for a certain element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't provide any code about you're using `NSPredicate`, so I wrote a simple example. Maybe this will help you.

```
@objc class Dummy: NSObject {
    let propertyOne: Int = 1
    let propertyTwo: Int = 1
    let propertyThree: NSDictionary

    init(dict: NSDictionary) {
        propertyThree = dict
        super.init()
    }
}

let arr: NSArray = [
    Dummy(dict: ["keyOne" : "one"]),
    Dummy(dict: ["keyOne" : "two"]),
    Dummy(dict: ["keyOne" : "three"]),
    Dummy(dict: ["keyOne" : "one"]),
    Dummy(dict: ["keyOne" : "five"])
]

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.propertyThree.keyOne == 'one'")
let results = arr.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
print(results)
```

Comment: Other possible syntax for getting value under key in dicitionary via a predicate is `self.propertyThree[\"keyOne\"]`

Comment: @Bannings, considering this question, if i want to filter 'int' variables then what should i do?

Comment: @Vats It will be like this:`let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.propertyOne == 1")`

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C:

```
[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate 
                         predicateWithFormat:@"propertyThree.keyOne = %@", value]];
```

In Swift you could use the adaptation of that but, as Kametrixom suggests, it'd be more normal to use `filter` and a closure; that's the mechanism that removes the dynamic key-value coding step.

Comment: I suppose that there is typo `.keyOne = %@` must be `.keyOne == %@`. Am I right, @Tommy?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, using real Swift:

```
class Dummy {
    let propertyOne: Int = 1
    let dict: [String : String]

    init(dict: [String : String]) {
        self.dict = dict
    }
}

let arr = [
    Dummy(dict: ["keyOne" : "one"]),
    Dummy(dict: ["keyOne" : "two"]),
    Dummy(dict: ["keyOne" : "three"]),
    Dummy(dict: ["keyOne" : "one"]),
    Dummy(dict: ["keyOne" : "five"])
]

let result = arr.filter { $0.dict["keyOne"] == "one" }
```

Few notes:

- You don't need your classes to inherit from `NSObject` in Swift, if they do though, the `@objc` attribute is implicitly applied anyways
- Use `[NSObject : AnyObject]` instead of `NSDictionary` as it's equivalent. I used `[String : String]` here because that's obviously what it is
- Using the `filter` method, you can filter your array in a typesafe way, also it's faster