# How would I loop through the NSMuttableArray, to check if an ID is same with a particular user id.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want a looping concept in order to find whether an id in my code is matched or same as that of already present in the `array`.(for example I want to check whether the id 12345 is present in the following `NSMutableArray`)
and  also wants to know on which index path it has occurred and how to change that

```
{
    artist = "Green Day";
    id = 1421768;
    name = "American Idiot";
    releasedate = "21 Sep 2004";
    runningtime = "57.53";
    tracks = "1: American Idiot\n2: Jesus of Suburbia\n3: Holiday/Boulevard Of Broken Dreams\n4: Are We The Waiting/St. Jimmy\n5: Give Me Novacaine/She's A Rebel\n6: Extraordinary Girl/Letterbomb\n7: Wake Me Up When September Ends\n8: Homecoming\n9: Whatsername\n";
    trackscount = 9;
    type = 1;
},
    {
    artist = Bastille;
    id = 309124896;
    name = "Bad Blood";
    releasedate = "1 Mar 2013";
    runningtime = "43.98";
    tracks = "1: Pompeii\n2: Things We Lost in the Fire\n3: Bad Blood\n4: Overjoyed\n5: These Streets\n6: Weight of Living, Pt. II\n7: Icarus\n8: Oblivion\n9: Flaws\n10: Daniel in the Den\n11: Laura Palmer\n12: Get Home\n13: Weight of Living, Pt. I\n";
    trackscount = 13;
    type = 1;
},
    {
    artist = "Lacuna Coil";
    id = 2025689;
    name = Comalies;
    releasedate = "16 Oct 2012";
    runningtime = "51.75";
    tracks = "1: Swamped\n2: Heaven's a Lie\n3: Daylight Dancer\n4: Humane\n5: Self Deception\n6: Aeon\n7: Tight Rope\n8: The Ghost Woman and the Hunter\n9: Unspoken\n10: Entwined\n11: The Prophet Said\n12: Angels Punishment\n13: Comalies\n";
    trackscount = 13;
    type = 1;
}
```

Comment: you can use -> [NSMutableArray containsObject : YourID];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering NSArray of NSDictionary objects using NSPredicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505154/filtering-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects-using-nspredicate)

Comment: `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` should do the trick.

Comment: Considering that "id" value is a NSString object: `NSUInteger index = [array indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(NSDictionary * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) { return [obj[@"id"] isEqualToString:@"3091248962"];}]; if (index == NSNotFound){ NSLog(@"Not found"); } else { NSLog(@"Index Found: %@", @(index)); }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = -1;     
for (int i=0; i< [arrJSON count]; i++){
    NSDictionary *dict = [arrJSON objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:@"123456"]){
       NSLog(@"Found at index: %d",i);
       index = i;
       break;
    }
}
if (index == -1){
    NSLog(@"ID not found");
}
```

Comment: This is also another way to solve this issue. But for loop is faster than predicates when the number of entries in the array is too large. If you don't have a complex UI in your app, both approaches work equally fine

Comment: @Pramod Tapaniya....thnkuu donee....but I also want  to get the information on which index it occurs(index path)...any answers

Comment: @Arun i have to use for loop now because Roby want to index also. :)

Comment: @Roby check answer.

Comment: @Roby if my answer solve your problem than accept as a correct answer.

Comment: Maybe better to use `NSUInteger` and `NSNotFound` instead of `int` and `-1`.

Answer (score -2):

```
BOOL isIDPresent = NO;
NSInteger index = 0;
for(; index < songsArray.count; index++) {
   NSDictionary *songDict = [songsArray objectAtIndex:index];
   if ([sondDict objectForKey:@"id"] == songId) {
      isIDPresent = YES;
      break;
  }
}
if (isIDPresent == YES) 
   NSLog(@"ID found at index : %d",index);
else
   NSLog(@"ID NOT FOUND");
```

where songsArray is the `NSMutableArray` and songId is the id you want to search for. The above code is valid when id is not a string. Check the code below if id is NSString

```
BOOL isIDPresent = NO;
NSInteger index = 0;
for(; index < songsArray.count; index++) {
   NSDictionary *songDict = [songsArray objectAtIndex:index];
   if ([[sondDict objectForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:songId]) {
      isIDPresent = YES;
      break;
  }
}
if (isIDPresent == YES) 
   NSLog(@"ID found at index : %d",index);
else
   NSLog(@"ID NOT FOUND");
```

Comment: i think for loop is not proper way.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Thanks @PramodTapaniya

Comment: In objective C, string comparission is not done by `==` operator

Comment: @SahebRoy From the data given in question, id doesn't looks like a string. That is why I gave == If it is a string you can use [[sondDict objectForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString: songId] instead

Comment: Edit your answer accordingly, as OP might find it usefull.

Comment: @Arun `[sondDict objectForKey:@"id"]` is an object, since you can only put objects into a NSDictionary. So `if ([[sondDict objectForKey:@"id"] isEqual: songId])` at least?

Comment: This algorithm performs *two* passes over the array - `for` and `indexOfObject:`- when only one is required.

Comment: Sorry but your edited version will always return that the item was found provided the array is non-empty, even if the item is not in the array.